# [REST]Modeling subresource response when resource does not exist

Tags: rest, api, resources, restful-url, http-response-codes

I am working on a REST api and have a question on sub-resources.

Assume I have an "article" resource and "comments" sub resource.

api/article/{articleId}/comments/{commentId}

a GET request with articleId = 5 and commentId = 2 will retrieve the comment number 2 of article number 5.

Now if the request contains a non-existing articleId how should I handle my response.

Should I send a response saying

1. this articleId does not exist with 404 not found
2. empty response
3. or any other

Answer (score 1):

HttpStatusCode 404 sounds about right in this scenario - the client probably won't even get to the point where it will request a particular comment. You can also have a look at this [guide](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/).